# Is there a simpler way to monitor changes to a piece of data, and disallow removing the data from monitoring?

Tags: python, data-types

I'm working on an algorithm visualizer for sorting algorithms. Give it a (user-submitted) sorting algorithm, hit run, it'll generate a random list of integers and show you what the algorithm looks like. But then you pause to think about this for more than 2 seconds and realize that this is easier said than done. You need a way of passing a list into a function that can spy on everything done to it and report back. Specifically, two features are needed:

1. Identify when two elements are compared
2. Identify when one or more elements are moved/swapped

This spying needs to work even when the user makes a temporary copy of one of the elements, with there being *nothing* a user can do with an element that removes it from view of the spying. For those functional language people out there, there's something distinctly [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))-smelling about this sort of problem.

My proposed solution is to wrap the number type and the list type and then reimplement *all* of the magic methods on both to sneak in the spying:

```
class Monitorable:

    def __init__(self, value):
        # Idempotent wrapping to handle use of Monitorables and other types
        if isinstance(value, Monitorable):
            # Tell the visualizer they're the same object
            self.__visualize_ref = value.__visualize_ref
            # Copy in the value
            self.__value = value.__value
        else:
            self.__value = value
            self.__visualize_ref = uuid()
            visualize_create(self)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        visualize_compare(self, other)
        return self.__value < other.__value

    def __gt__(self, other):
        visualize_compare(self, other)
        return self.__value > other.__value

    ...


class MonitorList:

    def __init__(self, values):
        self.monitorable_values = [Monitorable(val) for val in values]
        visualize_list(self)

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        visualize_setitem(self, key, val)
        self.monitorable_values[key] = Monitorable(val)

    ...
```

Planning this out before writing the code, this looks like a ridiculous amount of work to reimplement every single magic method just to throw a `visualize_x()` function in there and wrap the types in `Monitorable`. Is there a library or Python trick I'm missing to cut down on the hundreds of lines of boilerplate the spying is going to take?

Comment: Couldn’t you instead have a function or class that takes an IComparable, and two numbers? And then notifies the visualizer each time?